# Return result depend on conditions for multible rows without self join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large answers table like this

```
person_id|question_id|answer
1|101|6
1|102|2
1|103|5    
2|101|2
2|102|5
2|103|5    
3|101|2
3|102|8
3|103|6    
4|101|2
4|102|8
4|103|6
4|101|6
4|102|2
4|103|5
```

How to return persons depend on multiple question answers? For example I need to return person who answers:

```
6 for question 101 

and 2 for question 102 

and 5 for question 103
```

**the query should return person 1 and 4**

and consider that I need to filter depend on 10 questions, so I don't need to do 10 self join on the table :)

Comment: is question number is static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select person_id
from t
where (question_id, answer) in ( (101, 6), (102, 2), (103, 5) )
group by person_id
having count(distinct question_id) = 3;
```

Note that the "3" needs to match the number of questions you have in the `in` list.

Comment: after testing self join still much faster :(

Comment: @SahebSoft . . . An index on `(question_id, answer)` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM TableName
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN  question_id = 101 AND Ans=6 THEN 1 
               WHEN  question_id = 102 AND Ans=2 THEN 1 
               WHEN  question_id = 103 AND Ans=5 THEN 1 
          END
```

Comment: This query will return all who matched at least one condition (including "person 2"). But required persons with match all conditions (person 1 and 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PersonID 
FROM  (
            SELECT PersonID,
            CASE WHEN  question_id = 101 AND Ans=6 THEN 1 
                 WHEN  question_id = 102 AND Ans=2 THEN 1 
                 WHEN  question_id = 103 AND Ans=5 THEN 1 
            END  as [count]
            FROM TableName
            GROUP BY PersonID,question_id,Ans
                                                ) x
WHERE x.[count]=3
```